# How to find all links to private pages, javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's the scenario: Client request certain behavior (a lightbox) on the click of a link to a private page *when a site visitor is not logged into site*.

**KEY: Private pages on the site are not listed in the top navigation html until a user is logged in to the site.**

There are no parameters or identifiers for links going to private pages. *BUT* we can know which links are public by referencing the path names of the top navigation, thereby ruling out public links and external links, every other link on the page must be internal & private.

What we know:

- The URL Host (which we can use to find if link is internal or
  external
- Navigation Links that are public (we can find this from looking at our top navigation structure)
- External links (we can find this based on knowing the host URL)

Is it possible to know which links on a site are internal & private based on ruling out the known public & external links, what might be a way to write this using jQuery or JS?

**EDIT:** Links that are internal are not guaranteed to be relative, most likely they will be absolute

**EDIT 2.0:**

What I assume we can know...

Current URL (this needs to be dynamic as script will be used on multiple sites that move from production URLS to w/e the client chooses): http://example.com

External URL: ? could be anything, need to find that or rule out those links. I don't want to target those

This is an example of what the navigation looks like.

```
<div class="navigation">
    <a href="http://example.com/home"></a>
    <a href="http://example.com/about"></a>
    <a href="http://example.com/register"></a>
</div>
```

I do not want to target links displayed in the top navigation as these are always public. (again, this needs to be dynamic as the script will be used on multiple sites that move from production URLS to w/e the client chooses, and the client has the capability to make any pages public they need.)

So those would be the known URLs, href's & links.

What I want to target is the links that are still on http://example.com but not listed in the  `navigation` div.

Comment: Is there any indication of which pages are "private" within the url? As in `example.com/private/somepage`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all external links are absolute and all internal links are relative, you could do something like this:

```
$("a[href^='http']").addClass("external-link");
```

Otherwise, you could do something like this:

```
var knownExternalHosts = ["foo.com"];

$("a")
    .filter(function(){
        var found = false;
        knownExternalHosts.forEach(function(knownHost){
            if(~this.href.indexOf(knownHost)) found = true;
        }, this);
        return found;
    })
    .addClass("external-link")
;
```

**UPDATED ANSWER** (based on feedback)

This solution should match all links that are in the array.

```
var knownLinks = ["http://foo.com", "/foo"];
$("a")
    .filter(function(){
        var found = false;
        knownLinks.forEach(function(knownLink){
            if($(this).attr("href") === knownLink) found = true;
        }, this);
        return found;
    })
    .addClass("known-link")
;
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/moderndegree/sE4KL/

Comment: Links that are internal are not guaranteed to be relative, most likely they will be absolute, I am not looking to find external links but internal links that are not publically available

Comment: Then the second part of my answer will work just fine.

Comment: Your jsfiddle looks like it only targets the external vs/ internal links, also it looks like you are targeting the relative link structure which will not be the case - i may not be the best at explaining my problem though, sorry for any confusion